# How and why does a UPS generate AC power instead of DC?

Tags: power-supply, transistors

Most uninterruptible power supplies I've seen have standard AC mains outlets. From my limited understanding, it is essentially a battery pack that outputs current when it loses input power.

Given that batteries generate DC current, how does it convert it into AC output?
Also, why generate AC current if these units are primarily intended for electronic devices that run on DC current?

Wouldn't it be more cost effective and power efficient to output DC current, since it is already rectified?  Shouldn't most computer power supplies, for instance, should handle DC input.

Comment: Good question.  What DC output voltage do you think it should produce?

Comment: Whatever DC voltage after rectification?

Comment: Well, rectifying UK mains produces 339 VDC.  My motherboard runs on 3.3V and my drill is 18V.  My arc welder is 40V.  Not sure about those emergency light bulbs, they're 240VAC only.  Tricky.

Comment: You need to use your arc welder during a power outage???

Comment: It would be nice if there were a multi standard DC UPS providing 12V (for wireless router), 19V(for laptops), 5V(for USB chargers). This is kind of why "5V pass-through" aka "use while charging" is such a great feature among USB power banks.

Comment: Also if you google for "12V DC UPS" you will find a lot of DC UPS products, with the simplest one being a integrated fast switch and SLA battery charger between 12V DC input and out. https://www.amazon.com/Mini-Box-picoUPS-100-system-battery-backup/dp/B005TWE4GU

Comment: now that computers (laptops) and monitors (flat) use DC power, a DC-output UPS could be quite viable.

Comment: I can see a server standard emerging where power supplies are external and the power inputs are standardized by voltage, enabling the use of a less expensive DC UPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons:

**1) Standards**

A household, battery-based UPS outputs AC because AC is the standard input to many, if not all, household equipment. If you wanted to use DC, you would need to decide on a DC supply rail that everything would use, and this on top of the already existing AC system. You would also require polarized connectors. Finally, you would still need to send your DC voltage though a voltage regulator, since every circuit will require it's own voltage levels.

**2) Not everything can work with DC**

There are a few cases where systems will not work on DC. Ofcourse, an obvious one is everything with a transformer connected directly to the input. But there are others: For example, I know a lot of heatpumps for AC use induction motors. These will not run on DC, infact, they will appear as a short and be damaged. Granted, you usually don't want these on a UPS anyways, but who knows? Devices that would be more likley to be ran of of a UPS, that will not function on DC would be any form of LED light that uses a capacitive dropper. Anything that uses a Triac-bassed dimming would also not work. (I can keep going on listing devices that would not work for a while).

**3) DC is harder to switch**

Low frequency AC has the property that it is easier to switch mechanicly. With this, I mean physical power switches. The reason for this is that the arc formed when opening a switch will be equinguished by the zero-crossing of the voltage in AC. This is not the case in DC, and hence the arcs can last longer, damaging the switches.

**4) Other types of UPS by default output AC**

When used in combination with say diesel generators to allow for long (or even indefinite) autonomous operation, it's easier to just keep everything AC. The diesel generators will ouput AC by default.

**5) Sometimes it is done**

There are actually cases where we do have DC outputs. For example, I believe one of facebook's open-rack system uses a local 48V DC rail to power systems. The racks have local battery-backup UPS systems, directly hooked up to this 48V rail. Other supercomputer/datacenter systems have done similar things.

The way it is achieved: the devices that turn DC into AC are gennerally called "inverters". They are some form of switching powersupply that chops the DC into pulsing waveforms, which are then filterd to form a nice (or not nice) AC wave.

Comment: Facebook can't be directly running servers /tape libraries off the 48V though can it?  Are the servers mains and the UPSs 48VDC input?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at the documents. The way I remember it is that they integrated the UPS into a first powersupply stage - the PSU/UPS would turn whatever input voltage (likely something like 3-phase, 400V or similar) into 48V DC. Since they pretty much design their entire server themselves, I guess this 48V was stepped down on the motherboard to the 5V, 3.3V and CPU supply rails, replacing the common 12V rail in desktop/server systems.

Comment: I'm not sure if it still is, but it used to be common for telephone exchanges to run on 48VDC.  That meant that computers had to be specially fitted with 48V power supplies.  It had the great advantage that the "UPS" was nothing more than a pile of lead acid batteries.

Answer (score 3):

The first question is simple,  they use a power inverter to generate AC from the battery.

The second is just as easy. It's because UPS are designed as general purpose back up power for consumer products, which require AC power. The majority that do use AC to DC use a mix of DC voltages so a UPS would need to cover that range, making it unfeasible. Though the popularity of usb has meant that dc UPS are available (usb power banks).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of devices rely on alternating voltages to induce an isolated voltage i.e. power supplies that use conventional transformers. Induction  motors also spring to mind. These would burn on dc. Also residual current detectors that are used to trip the supply in the event of an earth fault current do not work on dc. They could be made to work on dc and everything could be made to work on dc but nobody is going to change rules that have been set in stone for decades and decades.

In short dc is not compatible with many loads and most protection devices.

Regards how a dc voltage is made to produce an ac voltage, first you need to create an oscillator, then an amplifier then, more often than not, use a transformer to step up the voltage to line ac voltages. Yes it's more inefficient but that's just the way it is for reasons of compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Because UPS manufacturers are unimaginative and haven't realized that there is a substantial market for a UPS that puts out 12VDC.  Existing UPS could simply skip the inverter and output 12VDC.  If you need another voltage, one could use either a voltage step-up or step-down device.  The advantage of this setup would be much longer runtime for the UPS as the DC to AC inverter suffers substantial energy loss.